# a long running SQL seems will not finished in postgresql DB

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6

in Postgres DB, found a simple select statement cost 1 days+ and seems will not finished. currently DB resource consumption is normal and I execute that SQL manually, but it completed in several seconds successfully.

and I executed SQL `"SELECT relation::regclass AS relname, * FROM pg_locks where pid = '2066446';` The results found, there are `8 "AccessShareLock" types` and `1 "ExclusiveLock" type`.

I am not sure this could help on debug this long running SQLs. Could you please give me some directions on how to debug further for this issue?

add query plan here:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add explain plan for the sql. Ex:  `EXPLAIN  select * from blah blah`. Edit your post and add output

Comment: @DigvijayS, Thanks, I added query plan in question description. :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, hi , I am sorry I added a wrong label before. Actually I am using 9.6